# Time complexity of HashSet.contains in Java

Tags: java, hashset

In [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sfuZzBLPcx4) the guy explaining says that this code

```
boolean sumOfTwo(int[] a,int[] b, int v)
{
    HashSet<Integer> difference=new HashSet();
    for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++)
    {
        int diff=v-a[i];
        difference.add(diff);
    }
    for(int i=0;i<b.length;i++){
        if( difference.contains(b[i]) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

has a linear time complexity but wouldn't the use of `.contains` make it quadratic time? Because `.contains` has to check every element of the set so it would have a time complexity of O(n) and it is looped.

Comment: What is `n`? Does the length of `difference` depend on `n`"

Comment: Not necessarily looped.   For example, if "difference" is a set represented by a hashtable, there is usually no looping.

Comment: This depends on the type of `difference`. If it is a hashed colleciton, like a `HashSet`, then a `contains()` operation takes constant time. If it is tree-based, like `TreeSet`, then a `contains()` takes `log(n)`. If it is a simple `List` or similar, then you're exactly correct. Therefore, we need to see the underlying type and its `contains()` implementation. EDIT: I looked at the video, it uses `HashSet` and that's indeed constant time for a `contains()`. If you do not know why, look up how `HashMap` / `HashSet` work.

Comment: I updated my post to show the full code. Difference is a hashset I didn't know contains() had different time complexity depending on the input type. Problem solved. Thanks!

Comment: "I didn't know contains() had different time complexity depending on the input type" it doesn't, it depends on the data structure you are calling `contains` on.

Comment: FWIW, this is not the actual code.  Java does not have 'Interger' or 'bloolean'  types.  And that reuse of 'difference' for two variables will cause trouble. To avoid mistakes, it's best to paste the actual code, don't retype.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `contains` in an [`HashSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) is performed in O(1) (constant time):

> This class offers **constant time performance for** the basic operations (add, remove, **contains** and size), assuming the hash function disperses the elements properly among the buckets.

So the `contains` doesn't affect the complexity of the whole algorithm